# Where to begin for post purchase facebook share capability (Newbie Alert)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an eCommerce site and after a purchase we would like to prompt the user to tell their friends about their savings / purchase.

So the person is on our site. They have completed their order and I prompt them brag to their friends about their savings today...Click Here.

When they "click here" I would post to their newsfeed (is this the right place I'm not a big facebook user)

So which app type would I use (I'll google tutorials once I know what to google for).

Again my apologies for the simple question and thank you!

Side Question:

Does facebook have a video education / tutorial section the way Microsoft does (MSDN) and Google does for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do with the Facebook's [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/), which can be used without a Facebook Application.

If you need more advanced functionality, e.g. from Facebook's [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) you can set up your app as a "Website with Facebook Login" and use the Javascript SDK to do everything you need.

Side Answer: Facebook has video education/tutorials on its [Developers Live](https://developers.facebooklive.com) site.